# Test Emails Not Working

Tags: civimail

Suddenly, CiviMail test emails are not working. Note that the emails themselves are going out without problems, just not the tests.

Any idea of the problem and how to troubleshoot?

CiviCRM version: 4.4.14
CMS: Drupal 7.36

Comment: I've got the same problem. AN/MP hosting cannot find any reason why mail would not be sent. I am testing a test install and using the PayPal sandbox. Everything works as far as the contribution, but no email is sent to the donor, Tell a Friend does not work, and Test Emails on the email settings panel don't arrive. Anyone know where to look? Besides the logs, which I have checked to death. No trace, no debugging info and no PHP errors.

Comment: Larry, it sounds like you probably should post a unique question for your issues which seem possibly different.

Answer (score 3):

Can you check on the log of your mail server if they are really not going out?

Usually when I have this problem, it's because the test emails are flagged as spam and discarded somewhere between civicrm and the inbox of the tester

Answer (score 2):

I think that test emails go out a different mechanism than the non-test ones (assuming you're talking about civimail). So you might want to check your local server, assuming your non-test civimail is going out via a different smtp.